# Place image on rectangle after detection in OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, native

I'm currently developing an android application where user can choose a shirt they want and it will be placed on top of their body with the use of the rear camera. The detection part is done and working and down below are the codes I've made so far.

**nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.h** //header file for nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
/* Header for class nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass */

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#ifndef _Included_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass
#define _Included_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass
 * Method:    humanDetection
 * Signature: (J)V
 */

 void detectHuman(Mat& frame);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass_humanDetection
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.cpp** //C++ File

```
#include "nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nerds_thesis_clartips_OpencvClass_humanDetection (JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba){
Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrRgba;

detectHuman(frame);
}

void detectHuman(Mat& frame){
// assign xml file to a variable
String human_cascade_name = "/storage/emulated/0/data/haarcascade_upperbody.xml";
CascadeClassifier human_cascade;

// load xml file
if(!human_cascade.load( human_cascade_name ) ) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return; };

std::vector<Rect> humans;
Mat frame_gray;
Mat original;
frame.copyTo(original);

//convert input to grayscale
cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
//increase image contrast
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray);

//Detect Human
human_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, humans, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(100, 100) );

//for (int i=0; i<humans.size(); i++)
    //rectangle(frame, Point(humans[i].x, humans[i].y), Point(humans[i].x+humans[i].width, humans[i].y+humans[i].height), Scalar(0,255,0));

Mat imageMask = imread("C:/Users/Requinala/AndroidStudioProjects/CLARTIPS/app/src/main/res/drawable/bluevelvet.png", 1);

// Draw the mask over all rectangles
for (size_t i = 0; i < humans.size(); i++){

    Rect r = humans[i];

    Mat humanROI = frame_gray( humans[i] ); //image of the upper body

    int h_temp = humans[i].height;    // storing original height
    int x = humans[i].x;
    int y = humans[i].y - h_temp*(-0.6); // y is increased by 0.6*h
    int w = humans[i].width;
    int h = h_temp; // height detected

    rectangle(frame,Point (x,y),Point(x + w,y +h),Scalar(255,0,255),1,4,0);

    /*int xx =0, yy =0;
    // Just iterate in face region pixel by pixel
    for(int x = humans[i].x; x < humans[i].x+humans[i].width; x++){
        for (int y = humans[i].y; y < humans[i].y+humans[i].height; y++){
            //Copy Mask to Original image  If the 0 chan
            //Proper condition is over all color channels
            //if (imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0] < 10){
                 // Copy to original image on (y,x) places  the pixel of xx,yy mask
                 humanROI.at(y,x)[0] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0];
                 humanROI.at(y,x)[1] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[1];
                 humanROI.at(y,x)[2] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[2];
            //}
            // Iterate in mask x
            xx =xx+1;
        }
        // iterate next row of imageMask
        xx = 0;
        yy =yy+1;
    }*/
}
}
```

However, I'm getting errors:
    no matching member function for call to 'at'
What should I do? Any help/ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: you should copy the whole error, to make it easier to understand... but I am almost sure that `humanROI.at(y,x)[0] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0];` is the problem, since `at` is templated and you need to do something like `humanROI.at<uchar>(y,x)`, also humanROI is 1 channel (is a subimage of a greyscale one), and imageMask is 3 channel... so this won't work... if you have 3 channels in both  you can do  `humanROI.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = imageMask.at<Vec3b>(xx,yy);` only once and copies the 3 channel pixel... with one channel use uchar.

Comment: I only have 1 channel for humaROI. How do I make 3 channels for it?

Comment: `cvtColor( matIn, matOut, CV_GRAY2BGR );` should do the trick this will just create a 3 channel mat and all of them will have the same information, thus the colors will be the same as in gray at least visually.... Also you may use `frame` and not `frame_grey` when you create the `humanROI`

Comment: Where should I put the second cvtColor since I already have one?

Comment: I did what you told me and now my camera stops upon detecting bodies. Please help.

Comment: That would be another question, try to keep them separated so that people can easily find the answer to the question. I will write my comments as an answer, if you can and if it compiles now, please accept it so that other people with the same problem finds the answer faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code:

```
        //if (imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0] < 10){
             // Copy to original image on (y,x) places  the pixel of xx,yy mask
             humanROI.at(y,x)[0] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0];
             humanROI.at(y,x)[1] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[1];
             humanROI.at(y,x)[2] = imageMask.at(xx,yy)[2];
        //}
```

it is easy to spot the problem. You are missing the template specification.

you can change it to the following:

```
        //if (imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0] < 10){
             // Copy to original image on (y,x) places  the pixel of xx,yy mask
             humanROI.at<uchar>(y,x)[0] = imageMask.at<uchar>(xx,yy)[0];
             humanROI.at<uchar>(y,x)[1] = imageMask.at<uchar>(xx,yy)[1];
             humanROI.at<uchar>(y,x)[2] = imageMask.at<uchar>(xx,yy)[2];
        //}
```

or even better:

```
        //if (imageMask.at(xx,yy)[0] < 10){
             // Copy to original image on (y,x) places  the pixel of xx,yy mask
             humanROI.at<Vec3b>(y,x) = imageMask.at<Vec3b>(xx,yy);
        //}
```

That should solve your compiling error, however the `humanROI` is in greyscale, you can do:

```
Mat humanColorROI;
cvtColor( humanROI, humanColorROI, CV_GRAY2BGR );
```

To get a 3 channel grey image. This way it should work.

P.S.: Regarding your stopping after detecting the body, it could be that it crashes or that you are just calling this function once? Is better to make another question for you to receive help from more members and for other members to find the answer quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I really appreciate your answer :) I will accept this answer because it helped me. I'll post another question then.